# Image not found for custom framework

Tags: ios, qt, clang, qmake

I have a custom .framework that I am trying to include in a Qt Quick iOS app. It compiles but when the app is run, it crashes saying:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/SharedMobileLib.framework/SharedMobileLib
  Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/.../App.App/App
  Reason: image not found
```

In the .pro file:

```
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -Fpath/to/framework
LIBS += -framework SharedMobileLib
```

How do I copy the framework with the app? I have been searching for the last hour for any ideas without any luck. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm no iOS guy, so this is just a shot in the dark. Does the -F option work like the -L option? In other words, does it expect just a path? It looks like you're actually giving it a .framework file. Does it work if you just use `-Fpath/to/framework`?

Comment: My mistake, I have the source code on another machine and retyped it here wrong. Will make an edit shortly